# IBM MobileFirst push notification icon for android

Tags: android, push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

Following the Android style guide, we've got a white-only icon for the notifications bar. (It seems it needs to be called `push.png` - the MFP code will crash the app trying to add it to the tray.)

Unfortunately, when we open the tray to look at the notification, it shows the notification bar icon on a black background.

I think setting both `android:icon` and `android:logo` on the `application` element in `AndroidManifest.xml` should work to get the behavior I want, namely that I have a white-only icon in the notification bar, but a color icon when the notification tray is opened. But it is not working with the notification added to the tray after an MFP push through GCM.

Here's the `AndroidManifest.xml` code I think should work (the `push.png` icon is the white-only version of the app icon):

```
<application android:label="@string/app_label"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:logo="@drawable/push">
```

Is there something else I should do to get the common Android notification behavior?

Answer (score 0):

If you observe a product crash, this will require opening a PMR so that the IBM development team will dedicate resource to investigate and possibly provide a fix.

Unless someone does have a fix in code for this?